# java spring URL mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I using maven web application, framework spring.

Using Netbeans IDE and Tomcat server.

When I run web in netbeans, URL in browser is:

http://localhost:8080/mywebsite

With this URL website cannot read event servlet mapping.

When I change URL to http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/ then It run good.

What is reason for this case? Why my website don't auto add character "/" in URL?

{update}

config.java

public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/*");
}

}
```

Initializer

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(Config.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
}
```

controller

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="ADMIN">
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(ModelMap map) {
    return "admin/login";
}}
```

Comment: @Abdelhak I updated in my question

Answer (score 1):

If you open `http://localhost:8080/mywebsite`, the web app will try to find some `index.html` file(based on tomcat or http server configuration).

And you mapping is `@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)`, so it will apply to `http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/`. If you want to use your controller to handle `http://localhost:8080/mywebsite`, you can try to use `*` in your mapping value. It means, for any request, if there is no specific mapping defined, and that default mapping will be applied.

Comment: I using spring and I override onStartup => When I run `http://localhost:8080/mywebsite` app will file index.jsp and show right. But when I submit event => call servlet event then failed because directions wrong.  Right is `http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/myevent` but now It is `http://localhost:8080/myevent`